# What is this tool? Need help with identification!

Tags: tools, workshop

When my father-in-law died we came across this while cleaning out his shop. There are no markings on it. It measures 8" x 2.5" x 2.5" and is made of 1/4" steel tubing. The side bolts tighten flat jaws in the slot. The end bolt just screws in so it must be mounted to something with this end bolt? He had a wood lathe, drill press and radial arm saw. I've searched the internet for accessories for the tools he owned and and can't find anything similar. Can anyone identify what this is?
[image]

Comment: It may be part of another tool.  Are there any power tools with a powder blue color in the shop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will go with knife vise. Looks like you are missing the base/stand.

*edit* it is actually called a Knife Makers Vise.

[knife vise](https://knifeandgun.com/products/knife-vise)

[different style](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/knife-vise-knife-makers-vise-clamp-1832214984)

[and another](https://www.mountainhollow.net/knife-vise.php)

Comment: Thanks Gunner. My father-in-law did make knives at one time so the knife vise is it. I'll look for the L bracket. I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: @TB, be sure and accept the best answer (check mark).  Normally we like to wait for a bit and see if a better answer will come in, but this is obviously the correct identification.